# Explode a dictionary of lists to get permutations of key to each value in list

Tags: python, pandas

How do I go from a dictionary like this:

```
j = {'BRAA': ['AEN-1', 'AMC-1', 'APL-1C'], 'BRAB': ['BRVO-1', 'CNBC-1']}
```

To a pandas dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Unit": ["BRAA", "BRAA", "BRAA", "BRAB", "BRAB"], "Network": ["AEN-1", "AMC-1", "APL-1C", 'BRVO-1', 'CNBC-1']})


   Unit Network

0  BRAA   AEN-1
1  BRAA   AMC-1
2  BRAA  APL-1C
3  BRAB  BRVO-1
4  BRAB  CNBC-1
​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
j = {'BRAA': ['AEN-1', 'AMC-1', 'APL-1C'], 'BRAB': ['BRVO-1', 'CNBC-1']}

df = pd.DataFrame([{'Unit': k, 'Network': i} for k, v in j.items() for i in v])

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Unit Network
0  BRAA   AEN-1
1  BRAA   AMC-1
2  BRAA  APL-1C
3  BRAB  BRVO-1
4  BRAB  CNBC-1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build the dataframe with [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) setting `orient='index'` and [`melt`](https://www.google.com/search?q=andas+melt&oq=andas+melt&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l6j69i60.1419j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

```
(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(j, orient='index').T
   .melt(var_name='Unit', value_name='Network')
   .dropna())

   Unit Network
0  BRAA   AEN-1
1  BRAA   AMC-1
2  BRAA  APL-1C
3  BRAB  BRVO-1
4  BRAB  CNBC-1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use another dictionary.

```
j = {'BRAA': ['AEN-1', 'AMC-1', 'APL-1C'], 'BRAB': ['BRVO-1', 'CNBC-1']}
dict = {"Unit":[], "Network":[]}

for key, val in j.items():
    for v in val:
        dict["Unit"].append(key)
        dict["Network"].append(v)

df = pd.DataFrame([dict])

print(df)
```